# Determine if an Object in Javascript has any properties

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var searchFilter = {_id: XXX, approved: true}
```

Which is used to drive a Meteor collection search filter.  I then have a pair of text boxes that allow the user to enter in a range of dates, in which case I update the filter to trigger Meteor to reactively re-run the filter, like so:

```
// Some Meteor event-handler...
  var val = // code to pull val in...not important...
  var searchFilter = Session.get('searchFilter');
  if (!val || val === '') {
    delete searchFilter.created_on;
  } else {
    searchFilter.created_on = {$gte: new Date(val)};
  }
  Session.set('searchFilter', searchFilter);
```

The else that removes the create_on child object works great for one field, but in my code I have two fields, one for a beginning range and one for an ending range.  What I need to be able to do is remove the created_on: {$gte}, then check if created_on is "empty", and if so, remove the whole thing.  I am not sure how I go about doing that, though.  Is this possible?  I have access to jQuery and underscore.js as libraries, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to see if any properties have been defined on an object. This will return an array of property names, so just check is it's length is greater than 0.

```js
// create the filter with $gte set
var searchFilter = {};
searchFilter.created_on = {$gte: new Date(56378563786)};

//  check if any properties are defined
var hasProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(searchFilter.created_on).length > 0;
alert("Has properties: " + hasProps);

// now delete $gte

delete searchFilter.created_on.$gte;

//  check if any properties are defined
var hasProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(searchFilter.created_on).length > 0;
alert("Has properties: " + hasProps);
```

Comment: Great answer, but bear in mind that if you're using Meteor, you have a built-in underscore.js method for exactly this, which is slightly more concise: [_.isEmpty](http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty)